# remove a value from Hashmap by onitemclicklistner in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

i am trying to remove values id and name from listview, where we user  ArrayList> DataListResult; and user ListAdapter  private ListAdapter adapter = null; when i have use DataListResult.clear(); it is work and it clear all list items but i want remove only one item by click.

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DataListResult = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 HashMap<String, String> DataList;
ListView listView;

private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = null;
private ListAdapter adapter = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_apointment__list, container, false);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                  toRemove= listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Object item = adapter.getItem(position);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(),  value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //DataListResult.clear();


            DataList.remove(item);
            ((BaseAdapter)adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });

    return v;

}
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        if(result == 1){


     //   arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DataListResult);
          //  listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                   getActivity(),DataListResult,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                    TAG_ID, TAG_NAME,
            }
                    , new int[] {
                    R.id.list_id,R.id.list_name,


            }

            );

           listView.setAdapter(adapter);

 private void parseResult(String result) {
    try{
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("appontment");

        for(int i=0; i< posts.length();i++ ){
            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
            String id = post.optString("id");
            String name = post.optString("name");

             DataList = new HashMap<String, String>();

            DataList.put(TAG_ID, id);
            DataList.put(TAG_NAME, name);

         //   DataList.remove(toRemove);
            DataListResult.add(DataList);



        }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

where i am doing mistake please anyone tell me.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
DataList.remove(item);
```

To

```
DataListResult.revome(position);
```

Comment: Thank You Sir it is working :) can i use DataList.remove(position); to remove values dynamically?

Comment: DataList is hashmap and you are storing it inside list DataListResult